# What does "solid four" mean?

Tags: dont-look-up

In *Don't Look Up* (2021), Professor Mindy is talking to Mrs Mindy on phone:

> Mindy: Hey, how's Evan feeling? Are the new meds working out?
>
> Evan: I'm a **solid four**.
>
> Mindy: Well, that's better than last month, right?

It’s hard to say exactly what scale is being used or what
the number ‘four’ means in this context.

What does "solid four" mean?

Comment: Four out of five would be great. Four out of ten would be not so great.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

He appears to be rating the effectiveness of his (anti-depressant?) medication on a scale. This would typically be out of five or out of ten.

In English it's not clear which he means, but in Spanish the dubbing is clearer:

> **Mindy:** *¿Cómo va la nueva medicación?* ("How is the new medication going?")
>
> **Evan:** *Cuatro sobre diez.* ("*Four out of ten*")

Comment: I think it's relatively clear from the context (especially the response) that this is out of ten, even just from the English. I would say in the absence of other clues, a single digit number is most likely to be out of ten, a two-digit number probably out of one hundred, and stars out of 5.

Comment: @dbmag9 - I didn't think it was especially clear, so I went and found a source that confirms it

Comment: Oh I'm all in favour of this answer and the confirmation, my comment was to help others with similar questions in different cases. I think the "That's better than last month, right?" indicates that Evan still isn't feeling great, which rules out 4/5.